# Respuesta JSON no funciona en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo una solicitud get en Laravel y todo bien, pero cuando no recibo datos mando una respuesta en json de esta forma:

```
public function index()
{
    $productos=Product::all(); //all select * from

    if($productos->isEmpty()){
        return response()->json([
            "status"=>"No elements in DB"
        ],Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }else{
        return response()->json($productos,Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Manda los resultados HTTP en ambos casos, pero cuando quiero mandar el `status` ya no aparece nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven justo pone el código de solicitud, pero no pasa, se pone el JSON de status, ¿Por qué pasa esto? ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar? Gracias, estoy el Laravel 10.x

Comment: El problema puede ser el código de respuesta que estás utilizando. Aparentemente un 204 no lleva contenido y puede ser que esté siendo descartado. Probá usar otro código para corroborar que el problema viene por ese lado.

Comment: ¡En efecto ese era el problema…!!! Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo publiqué como respuesta para que la pregunta pueda quedar marcada como resuelta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es el código de respuesta que estás utilizando. [204](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) no permite enviar contenido.
Con cambiar el código se soluciona tu problema.